# How to remove front tag from landing page and logged in home page?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a D7 website on the production environment. On the landing page and logged in page i see the page head title "Front | XXXXXXXXXX". Basically xxxxxx is portal name. I would like to remove the Front keyword from the title and show only XXXXXXXXX.

I tried with several options like
- handling in the template.php with in goodnex_preprocess_page()
- handing via module with hook_init().

Please suggest how to fix it.

Comment: It probably relates to metatag module. Check if it is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

There is th module [Page Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_title) that fixed this. Also if you're using [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag), its functionality has moved into the module. They should let you use a custom title that will remove your site name.